# How to specify that .PDF form fields use specific fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdf, forms

Is there a way to embed a font in an interactive .pdf so that only it can be used to type in fields?

I am fairly certain that InDesign doesn't have this capability, but do you know if this is at all possible in other programs?

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the font for form fields in Acrobat, that font gets fully embedded (except CJK fonts, of course). It may be that InDesign does that too, but in this respect, I would not trust InDesign (could by my prejudice).

Conclusion, use Acrobat to finish the form fields.

Comment: +1 About trusting Acrobat for this. Usually, form field font cannot be too specific and are limited to system fonts. They can't really be embedded as they are kind of dynamic and the user would need to have them installed on his/her system too! It's safer to limit the form field to system fonts even though it's not super fancy... at least it's reliable!

Comment: @go-junta: Actually, it is possible to use any (embeddable) font in form fields (except the already mentioned CJK fonts, because of their size). The fonts get fully embedded, which causes the file size to considerably increase. That means, the users do NOT need to have the font on their system. Restricting to "system fonts" (I guess you talk of the ones that appear at the very top of the font list in the field properties dialog in Acrobat) does insofar make sense, as forms are/have to be more robust than other kind of documents.

Answer (score -1):

Print PDF InDesign can embed fonts, interactive PDF InDesign can only embed Times New Roman.

After export, in Acrobat use this JavaScript to change them to what you want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    if (this.getField(fname).type == "text") {
        this.getField(fname).textFont = "Arial";
    }
}
```